# Iterating through MapPartitionsRDD - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am going through somebody else's Scala code and I am having trouble iterating through a `RDD`. I just want to print its contents.

```
val neighborRDD : RDD[(Long, Array[(Row, Double)])]
```

This is the `RDD` that I want to see. What people suggest in other questions -- `neighborRDD.foreach(println)` -- doesn't work, with or without `.collect()`.
Any help on this?

Edited : Add error message when I do neighborRDD.foreach(println)

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/yhkwon/Desktop/knn/spark-knn/python/test.py", line 33, in
>   
>       predictions = model.transform(test)   File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/base.py", line
>   105, in transform   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py", line
>   281, in _transform   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line
>   63, in deco   File
>   "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 319, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o99.transform. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 13.0 (TID 32, 192.168.0.18, executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row  at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.classification.KNNClassificationModel$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(KNNClassifier.scala:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.classification.KNNClassificationModel$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(KNNClassifier.scala:183)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:916)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:916)   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.classification.KNNClassificationModel.transform(KNNClassifier.scala:164)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row  at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.classification.KNNClassificationModel$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(KNNClassifier.scala:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.classification.KNNClassificationModel$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(KNNClassifier.scala:183)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more

Comment: it works for me. whats the error or problem are you getting when you do `neighborRDD.foreach(println)`?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row    -- I am getting this line

Comment: can you update the question with the error message and the exact line where the error occured?

Comment: @YongHyunKwon You can try this `neighborRDD.foreach{ case (longValue, array) => println(longValue + " " + array.toList)}`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I just added to my original question. I don't know how to change that whole error mesage into code block.. sorry about that :(

Comment: Your error message says that you are using pyspark. but your code looks is in scala how?

Comment: @AkashSethi Causes pretty much same error message with .foreach(println).

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I am using one of pyspark-packages. I think basic algorithms are written in scala and with pyspark just set the parameters.

Comment: why don't you use scala packages?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Our app is in python so i think it should eventually work in pyspark.

Comment: I am not sure but you should change the scala code to python too. :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan The package works by itself in our python app. If you look into python folder, I think thats where things are chonaged to python. I want to extract just KNN algorithm from the package, and thats where I am having trouble with.